# Futuristic visual style - Thor: Ragnarok, Transistor video game

Tags: terminology

What is this colorful and futuristic visual style you can see in *Thor: Ragnarok* the *Transistor* video game?

[*Thor: Ragnarok* - end credits - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F3gdrDqZpKM).

[image: Transistor poster]

[image: Transistor game play]

Comment: Welcome LL&P. You might have more luck making a single word request on our sister site: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions . Of course you'd want to take the tour there and read the help section on asking questions to get a feel for the way they work. Buhfik t' kunli tor du!

Comment: Dunno... "futuristic style" seems on-topic, even if as Duck said, this kind of terminology question is probably a better fit for ELU (or Movies perhaps?)

Comment: Those two works of art do not habe the same style.

Comment: @Duckisaduckisaduck Your comment [inspired a new question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/207953/31394).

Comment: @Randal'Thor Thanks for the head's up, and  - bizzare!

Answer (score 2):

The style is called Retrofuturism.

[image: Future is here]

> The use of a style or aesthetic considered futuristic in an earlier era.
>
> — Definition of retrofuturism, [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/retrofuturism)

Comment: Some (sourced) sources/examples would be nice.