# What does “Buhfik t' kunli tor du!” mean in Vulcan?

Tags: star-trek, vulcan

A user posted [this comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/205530/futuristic-visual-style-thor-ragnarok-transistor-video-game#comment561672_205530). At the end of it, the comment reads:

> Buhfik t' kunli tor du!

What does this mean? Rand al’Thor says it’s in Vulcan, but their translation seems uncertain.

Comment: I miss the days when google translate included options for invented languages like Klingon and Quenya... :(  FWIW, it says that it means "troubleshoot this morning" in Uzbek. :)  Seems appropriate to me...

Comment: There seems to be a dearth of Vulcan/English translators online. The one I could quickly find translates this as "perfect belonging to happy do you", which leaves me skeptical of its accuracy.

Comment: I'll let it play out for a while, see if anyone hits the linguistic nail on it's head. Hint: What does Vulcan culture not permit.....;-)

Comment: Vulcan word order is VSO (verb-subject-object). The verb to be (nam-tor) can be dropped when its meaning is clear from context. Unsure what word order this sentence is, though.

Comment: The -ik ending indicates an adjective (which "perfect" is anyway), which makes the dropped-"to be" make sense. Haven't figured out the posessive in the sentence.

Comment: I thought that Rand al’Thor was The Dragon Reborn, am I missing something?

Comment: @Walkerbo That would be me, not the character :-)

Comment: @Rand al’Thor  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## What does “Buhfik t' kunli tor du!” mean in Vulcan?

The question: What does it mean?

There is a distinction here between that and: What was it intended to mean?

**It's meaning:**

It's garbled because of approximate translation issues, I reffer you to the next sentence.

**What was it intended to mean?**

I used this [online translator](https://lingojam.com/EnglishtoVulcanTranslator) to translate a short phrase.

Since the Vulcan language regards concepts of belief as irrational and not worthy of consideration, it denies the concepts of superstition - not only to the extent of them posessing any validity, but to the existence of words to describe them.

<sub>*(This is entirely the opinion, related actions and recollections of the author of the original cited post and should not be construed as containing any cannonical weight whatsoever.)*</sub>

The short phrase put in was "Best of luck to you."

Answer (score 3):

According to [this online Vulcan-English dictionary](https://word-house.ru/uploads/2016/11/Vulkansko-angliyskiy-slovar.pdf) (whose canonicity I'm unsure of, but then who's saying a random SE comment would be using canonically correct Vulcan anyway):

- buhfik = perfect
- kunli = happy
- tor = do, make
- du = you

The last three words then seem to be quite clearly "make[s] you happy". Perhaps the whole thing is meant to be "perfection makes you happy"?

<sub>Maybe one of our Trekkies or constructed-language experts can do better ...</sub>

Comment: I can use a couple of online translation tools (https://funtranslations.com/vulcan and https://lingojam.com/EnglishtoVulcanTranslator) to reproduce the output with the input string "perfect of happy makes you" which is basically a word-replacement based on this dictionary: https://www.starbase-10.de/vld/  According to it, "t'" is "of" or "belongs to."

Comment: "perfect belonging to happy do you" reminds me of how Yoda in Star Wars would speak

Comment: I suspect it's an idiomatic phrase, closest to "Practice makes perfect"

Comment: @vbartilucci Rather something along the lines of "[Nothing short of]/[only] perfection should/will/can satisfy you", isn't it?